# Azure Service Bus Feature

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a simple question about azure Bus, i am trying to use it with azure functions and i intend to reduce the cost of the azure function due to polling of the azure service bus for messages is there a way to have the message sent out from azure service bus to an endpoint the moment the message is received. without using event grid ?

Comment: Functions (consumption) already reduce the cost because you don't have to poll yourself. But it's still polled on your behalf by Functions. What I don't understand in your question is what's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Are you asking if you can dispatch an outgoing message from a Function due to an incoming message the function handles? If that's the question, the short answer is 'yes'. If that's not your question, perhaps expand on the question itself.

Comment: Thanks sean feldman for the comment I understand that the polling is handled by the functions, i am trying to minimize how many time my function runs, i am triggering an azure function using azure service bus, each time the function runs to poll the service bus for messages i get a charge irrespective of whether the message is there or not, i am asking if there is a way to receive messages from the queue bus instantly but only when there is a message basically to prevent constant polling by the function.

Comment: You don't poll from a function. It's done on your behalf. When a function triggered by Service Bus is invoked, it means there are messages the function will be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! As per Sead Feldman, it is true. On your behalf, it is polled by the Service Bus when a function is triggered, it gives if messages available.

AFAIK, because of the underlying service architecture, the ServiceBusTrigger is on a **polling** basis.

As per this [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#azure-service-bus), the characteristics of a Azure Service Bus is:

> is a reliable asynchronous message delivery (enterprise messaging as a service) that requires polling

The same issue is registered in the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/714) that Polling costs is high with Service Bus Queue triggers even in zero activity of the Azure Functions.

From that GitHub discussion,  switching to [Azure Event Grid Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203&tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp) is the good option because [Azure Service Bus integrates with Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/servicebus/azure-service-bus-now-integrates-with-azure-event-grid?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) as Service Bus will send events to Azure EventGrid when there are new messages which would prevent you from polling.

Comment: ThankYou i thought there was another way to avoid event grid.